# Any substitute instead of windows service?

Tags: .net, windows-services

We have "fat" windows service doing plenty of the operations like database insert/update/delete AND calling some restful web service to update external systems. The service gets executed every 3 minutes and real business depends upon this service.

Sometimes the service gets into non-responsive mode, we are trying to fix that part. But this question is not about that issue.

At the other hand, we are thinking about applying any new technology or architecture. (Strictly Microsoft based)

At this point of time, I would like to know is there any substitute of windows service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows service is a fine tool when you need an autonomous application. One other way of doing it is to have regular application that can be started on Windows startup. But there is no major difference from service besides some security items, which for application to run, user must logon into machine.

What you need to work on is - on making your service application independent from processes. In other words, make your service a dispatcher but let end points to handle actual tasks. Majority of people simply do not write their services correctly. For example, I see a lot of services that have to do some DB calls on startup, etc. Startup should be simple - init the service, make an initialization call on separate thread. Also, you mentioned that you have service, which runs every 3 minutes. Why not add a port listener with port configurable through configuration. Same thing in applications that perform something. Application can then send a call to the service port and at this moment your service will know that there is work to do, instead of constantly checking.

There are many architectural techniques that can be applied to your windows service in order to make it robust and responsive. Apply them and you don't have to look for alternatives.

Comment: There is a major difference between a windows service and a regular application that's started at windows startup.  Windows services run without any user logged on.  Regular applications require that the user be logged on before they can be run.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch, I forgot to mention that and fixed it

Comment: Thanks T.S. Can you please suggest some links to go through for the different architectural guide (best practices) for windows service?

Comment: @StartingFromScratch May be you get some ideas here http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2005/10/01/write-a-better-windows-service.aspx and here http://blog.themobilebrand.com/technology/tutorial-building-a-windows-service-application/  I just happen to create multiple designs for services and never had a problem with responsiveness. If you nail the design right - you are going to be well with windows service. Also remember about plag-in architecture that can be very useful in win services

Answer (score 1):

You could write an executable and use the Windows Scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of technologies... the questions is, why do you want to change?  Is there a reason this is not working for you?  If so, what are those reasons?

For example, You could write your application as we Web Service, and simply have a schedule task that calls the web service periodically.  You could also put the service "in the cloud" and use Azure Worker Roles.  But all of these things typically have reasons to choose them... It's not clear what your requirements are.

Answer (score 0):

It depends how Fat your service is, and how big the business is.

You could re-architecture completely to push your various touch points into web services and then implement something like BizTalk to orchestrate the calling of these various services.

This obviously requires a lot of investment, SQL servers to back BizTalk, BizTalk application servers, someone to administrate the new tech.